# How do I display data from one of the columns (not static content) inside of a tool-tip upon click in jquery datatables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables, jquery-ui-tooltip

Below is the javascript that I'm using inside of my webpage. 
I'm sure there's a way to add a tooltip while using some of the code below, I just haven't figured it out.
If I can take header data and put in in a searchbox which I've done below, then I should be able to take table cell data and put it in a tooltip. The questions is how??

```
    // DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

 //this just is code that adds search headers 
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        var data = 
        $(this).html('<input type="text" title = data  style= "font-size:.6em" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    });






    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every(function () {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                that
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: this example uses qtip2 plugin to display tool tips on the first column http://jsbin.com/muhados/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [createdCell](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) callback.  This allows you to manipulate the cell content before it gets displayed.  In the below I'm adding a `title` attribute to the 4th column (index 3):

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
 "columnDefs": [ {
 "targets": 3,
 "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        $(td).attr('title',cellData);
       }
    }]
});
```

Here's a working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0ct2hbx/1/)

This will apply the standard `title` tooltip to the cell which is displayed on hover.  You could do something more fancy with a jquery-ui component, you'd just bind the event in the callback.